# 2 items from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples:

```
Items = [(4, 2), (1, 1), (2, 4), (8, 6), (11, 4), (10, 2), (7, 3), (6, 1)]
```

and I want to get it like so in a `for` loop:

```
NewItems = [[(4, 2), (1, 1)], 
            [(2, 4), (8, 6)],
            [(11, 4), (10, 2)],
            [(7, 3), (6, 1)]]
```

I did this:

```
NewItems = []
while len(Items) > 0:
    NewItems.append([Items[0], Items[1]])
    del Items[0:2]
print NewItems
```

I don't think it's the best way, since I'm deleting `Items` variables.
Then I tried to do this:

```
newList = iter(Items)
NewItems = []
for a, b in zip(newList, newList):
    NewItems.append([a, b])
print NewItems
```

but that's merging the tuples.

Is there any better solution that can do the same thing?

Comment: You can make list of tuples like this, `zip(Items,Items[1:])`

Comment: What's wrong with the iter version? It seems to generate the desired output. You obviously don't need an explicit for loop just a list comprehension `NewItems = [list(x) for x in zip(newList, newList)]`. And if you don't mind tuples instead of lists then even simpler: `NewItems = list(zip(newList, newList))`. The iter version avoids the creation of any intermediate lists - so is my preferred approach.

Comment: @AChampion yeah, that's was my mistake, i should just use a single variable from the loop and append it as a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension where you zip the items in pairs.

```
Items = [(4, 2), (1, 1), (2, 4), (8, 6), (11, 4), (10, 2), (7, 3), (6, 1)]
New_Items = [list(pair) for pair in zip(Items[::2], Items[1::2])]

>>> New_Items
[[(4, 2), (1, 1)], [(2, 4), (8, 6)], [(11, 4), (10, 2)], [(7, 3), (6, 1)]]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind tuples of tuples instead of the inner lists, just zip it up:

```
>>> zip(Items[0::2], Items[1::2])
[((4, 2), (1, 1)), ((2, 4), (8, 6)), ((11, 4), (10, 2)), ((7, 3), (6, 1))]
```

Comment: Just a note that neither of these returns a `list` in py3. OP was using py2.7 so not an issue but `list(zip(...))` is portable.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> items = [(4,2),(1,1),(2,4),(8,6),(11,4),(10,2),(7,3),(6,1)]
>>> new_items = [items[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(items), 2)] 
>>> new_items
[[(4, 2), (1, 1)], [(2, 4), (8, 6)], [(11, 4), (10, 2)], [(7, 3), (6, 1)]]
```

You can do it with the while loop like this.

```
>>> new_items = []
>>> while items:
...     new_items.append((items.pop(0), items.pop(0)))
... 
>>> new_items
[((4, 2), (1, 1)), ((2, 4), (8, 6)), ((11, 4), (10, 2)), ((7, 3), (6, 1))]
```

However this is destructive to `items` and isn't very efficient due to using `pop(0)` which is O(n)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Items = [(4,2),(1,1),(2,4),(8,6),(11,4),(10,2),(7,3),(6,1)]

NewItems = []
j =0   
for i in xrange(1,len(Items)-1): 
    if j+1 > len(Items):
        break
    NewItems.append([Items[j],Items[j+1]])
    j += 2

print NewItems
```

Comment: This still gives the wrong result.  `[[(1, 1), (2, 4)], [(2, 4), (8, 6)], [(8, 6), (11, 4)]]`

Comment: [[(4, 2), (1, 1)], [(2, 4), (8, 6)], [(11, 4), (10, 2)], [(7, 3), (6, 1)]]

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import time

Items = [(4,2),(1,1),(2,4),(8,6),(11,4),(10,2),(7,3),(6,1)]
NewItems = []
start_time = time()
while len(Items) > 0 :
    NewItems.append([Items[0],Items[1]])
    del Items[0:2]
print NewItems
print time() - start_time

Items = [(4,2),(1,1),(2,4),(8,6),(11,4),(10,2),(7,3),(6,1)]
NewItems = []
start_time = time()
for i in range(len(Items) / 2):
    NewItems.append([Items[2*i],Items[2*i + 1]])
print NewItems
print time() - start_time
```

With some timing so you can verify that the second solution is faster

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, but probably not the prettiest.

```
x = []
i = iter(Items)

while True:
    try:
        x.append([i.next(), i.next()])
    except StopIteration:
        break
```